# Azure DevOps classic pipeline NuGet not restoring latest package version

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore, azure-artifacts

I'm having an issue where NuGet is restoring an old package version from Artifacts. Once the revision number reached .10 the NuGet continues to restore the older version which is .9.

NuGet Version running on the Azure DevOps server: 6.7.0.127

Here is an image of the two version numbers of the artifact:
[image: Here is an image of the two version numbers of the artifact.]

I've tried setting the advanced option to Disable local cache but the Restore step still uses the older package version of .9.
I've tried deleting the package from the server and NuGet still restores the older version. I'm at a loss to why this is happening.

Comment: The  +23307 at the end is just metadata for year and day of the year which is not part of the version number. It's dropped and not considered at all by NuGet. It looks more like an issue with caching. I figured out that by using a wild card  on package references has fixed my issue. Thank you for the input.

Comment: Thanks @cbkinor. (I have removed my comment because the information was not correct.)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the documentation "[**Install and manage packages in Visual Studio using the NuGet Package Manager**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio)" to restore the latest package versions:

1. Open your project (such as **`.sln`** or **`.csproj`**) in Visual Studio.
2. Open the "**NuGet package manager**" window in Visual Studio to connect to your feeds.
3. Find and install the required packages from the connected feeds.
4. On the "**NuGet package manager**" window, you can install a package version, uninstall a package version and update the package version to the latest for your project.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm not having any issues with Visual Studio. This is related only to my build pipelines.

Comment: @cbkinor, After you updated the referenced package version to the latest for your project in Visual Studio, did you push the changes of your project to the remote Azure Git Repos?

Answer (score -1):

Please note that NuGet has a local package cache on the build server. Sometimes, cached versions can cause issues. You've mentioned that you tried to disable the local cache, but ensure that you did this correctly in your pipeline or local development environment.

In your Azure DevOps pipeline, use the NuGetCommand task to disable the local cache. You can add the -NoCache option to your NuGet restore step in your pipeline YAML.

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
     command: 'restore'
     restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
     feedsToUse: 'select'
     nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
     arguments: '-NoCache'
```

Do ensure that the repository where the nupkg files are stored (local, network, or remote) doesn't contain older versions of the package that NuGet might be picking up.

Also try adding a clean step before restoring packages to ensure that any cached data is removed.

```
- script: dotnet clean
  displayName: 'Clean'
```

Also verify that you have the correct version of the package referenced. Sometimes, it might be referencing a specific version.

And last but not the least If you're using a custom NuGet feed (e.g., Azure Artifacts or a custom package repository), verify the package versions available in the feed. Ensure that the version you want is correctly published to the feed. Also, ensure that your Azure Artifacts feed has the correct settings.

Comment: Thank you for responding. We unfortunately are currently using Classic Pipelines and not YAML. One of the steps  is NuGet Restore which I have applied the checkmark to "Disable local cache".